# How to process svgs used within angular.js templates using webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I'm trying to cache bust my svgs and other files such as translation json.

The problem I'm encountering is webpack isn't recognizing svgs imported like shown below:

```
<md-icon md-svg-src="assets/icons/ic-edit.svg"></md-icon>
```

I want to be able to hash this name so I can't just use CopyWebpackPlugin to copy and hash my assets as it would need to be updated within the markup also.

```
{
   test: /\.svg$/,
   loader: 'file-loader',
   options: {
     name(file) {
        // doesnt log anything as not picking up urls within angular templates
        console.log(file); 
        return '[name]-[hash].[ext]'
    }
  }
}
```

What options do I have to process svgs within my app? It would be a really large refactor to move all svgs from within the template and importing them in the js and using them inline that way but is that the only option I have? is what I'm looking for even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get svgs to be processed by webpack It took a few steps to get there, please note this is for webpack2 and you may need to change what I've done here to match your webpack version.

1. I need to define custom src attributes that angular uses to attach
   an svg to an icon
2. I needed to define when the html should start parsing absolute paths using root
3. I needed to add a name prop for assets and i used file loader for this

I also had to rename my asset paths from:

`"assets/icons/ic-edit.svg"`

`"/assets/icons/ic-edit.svg"`

```js
{
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loaders: 'html-loader',
        options: {
          // I had to define custom srcs
          attrs: ['md-icon:md-svg-src', ':ng-src'],
          // define where the html-loader should start parsing absolute paths
          root: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
          name: '[name]-[hash].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          // the hash for when svgs have been found
          name: '[name]-[hash].[ext]'
        }
      }   
    ],
  }
}
```